# Templates for CPT not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates, template-hierarchy

I am working on a project where I have created 3 CPT with some taxonomies. For each custom post type, I have created the following custom templates:

- single-
- archive-
- taxonomy-

*Taking as example the "Spa design" CPT.*

I created the templates:

- single-spa-design.php
- archive-spa-design.php
- taxonomy-spa-design.php

But those templates are not working and for the other two CPT neither. For some reason, Wordpress is getting the single.php , archive.php and taxonomy.php instead.

I thought the problem could be the '-' dash between 'spa-design', but the other two CPT are 'Projects' and 'Products' and they are not working either.

This's the code "Spa design" CPT and the Taxonomy associated to this CPT and for the other two CTP are basically the same.

```
// Adding Spa Design Custom Post Type.
add_action( 'init', 'spa_design_cpt' );
function spa_design_cpt()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Spa Design',
        'singular_name' => 'Spa Design',
        'menu_name' => 'Spa Designs',
        'name_admin_bar' => 'Spa Design',
        'all_items' => 'All Posts',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Post',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Post',
        'new_item' => 'New Post',
        'view_item' => 'View Post',
        'search_items' => 'Search Posts',
        'not_found' =>  'No posts found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No posts found in Trash.',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Page',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'               => $labels,
        'public'               => true,
        'exclude_from_search'  => true,
        'publicly_queryable'   => true,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_in_menu'         => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'    => true,
        'has_archive'          => true,
        'menu_position'        => 5,
        'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-admin-customizer',
        'hierarchical'         => true,
        'rewrite'              => array( 'slug' => 'spa-design','with_front' => true,'feeds' => false,'pages' => true ),
        'query_var'            => true,
        'can_export'           => true,
        'supports'             => array( 'title','editor','author','thumbnail' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'spa-design', $args );
    $labels = array(
        'name'                        => 'Design Type',
        'singular_name'               => 'Design Type',
        'menu_name'                   => 'Design Type',
        'all_items'                   => 'All Designs',
        'edit_item'                   => 'Edit Design',
        'view_item'                   => 'View Design',
        'update_item'                 => 'Update Design',
        'add_new_item'                => 'Add New Design',
        'new_item_name'               => 'New Design Name',
        'parent_item'                 => 'Parent Category',
        'parent_item_colon'           => 'Parent Category',
        'search_items'                => 'Search Design',
        'popular_items'               => 'Popular Design',
        'separate_items_with_commas'  => 'Separate design with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'         => 'Add or remove design',
        'choose_from_most_used'       => 'Choose from the most used design',
        'not_found'                   => 'No design found.',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                      => $labels,
        'public'                      => true,
        'show_ui'                     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'           => true,
        'show_tagcloud'               => false,
        'meta_box_cb'                 => null,
        'show_admin_column'           => false,
        'hierarchical'                => true,
        'query_var'                   => true,
        'rewrite'                     => array( 'slug'
                                  => 'design-type','with_front' => true,'hierarchical' => false, ),
        'sort'                        => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'design-type', array( 'spa-design' ) , $args );
}
```

I really don't know what is wrong here. I am using the latest version of Wordpress 4.8.2, I don't have any plugin installed, and I have flushed the permalinks trillions of times in the permalink settings..

Any idea what is wrong?

Many thanks,

Comment: try the plugin "Query Monitor", it will show in the admin bar which templates are used and the order of search. https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Comment: @mmm Thank you, I will do. I didn't know that plugin. Many thanks ;)

Comment: +1 for Query Monitor troubleshooting. With projects and products, you may be confusing singular and plural. The post types should be registered as singular (project & product) rather than plural.

Comment: maybe a bit  simple here, but you've obviously flushed permalinks, correct?

Comment: Singular or plural is irrelevant, as long as it’s consistent. Also, `taxonomy-spa-design` will never work, as that’s your post type, not your taxonomy.

Comment: Hi @rudtek yes, I have flushed permalinks correctly.  'Settings' >> 'Permalinks' >> 'Save changes' Or change it to 'Plain' Save changes and after that changes to the one you need, in my case 'post name'. Also I have used the function 'flush_rewrite_rules();'